# OpenSSL toolset in native Java

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, pfx, pkcs#12

I am searching a way to create/sign certificates in java.
At the moment I am using `openSSL` and I want to avoid to call this process from java code.

In detail I am using the following lines of code in `openSSL`

```
export ALTNAME=$altname;export SUBJECTALTNAME=email:$email;$openSSL genrsa 2048 > $serverKey;

export ALTNAME=$altname;$openSSL req -new -key $serverKey -config $config -days $days -out $serverCSR -subj \"/C=<TLD>/ST=<Location>/O=<Company> /OU=<Department>/CN=$cname\";

export ALTNAME=$altname;$openSSL ca -config $config -days $days -key $caCRT -keyfile $caKey -in $serverCSR -out $serverCRT -key <key>;

export ALTNAME=$altname;$openSSL pkcs12 -export -out $serverPfx -inkey $serverKey -in $serverCRT -certfile $caCRT;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use keytool tool that comes with java.

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html here is a explanation.

the command is : `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048`

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to use keytool like a library. Therefore it is necessary to run a process which executes the command(s). I want to use native Java code not run a process which is like "fire and forget". 
The posted command is for a self signed certificate which is completely different to that what my posted commands in connection with `openssl` will achieve. Please correct me if I am wrong.